# When uploading data from parquet to the Impala table in overwrite mode, an error occurs, PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I need to upload data from parquet to Impala database table using Spark and Python, here's how I do it

```
read_data = spark.read.parquet("file.parquet")

read_data.write.mode('overwrite')\
.option("driver", "com.cloudera.impala.jdbc4.Driver")\
.jdbc("jdbc:impala:*parameters of db*", "table")\
```

An error occurs:

```
> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o299.jdbc.
> java.sql.SQLException: [Cloudera][ImpalaJDBCDriver](500051) ERROR processing query/statement. Error Code: 0, SQL state: TStatus(statusCode:ERROR_STATUS, sqlState:HY000, errorMessage:ParseException: Syntax error in line 1:
> CREATE TABLE sbx_001.eliza1 ("app_id" DECIMAL(15,0) , "ap...
>                              ^
> Encountered: STRING LITERAL
> Expected: DEFAULT, IDENTIFIER
> 
> CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error
```

If I use the mode "add" in table, then there are no errors. But if I try to create a table first (as in `overwrite`), I get an error. Spark puts quotes in the request ( `"app_id" DECIMAL(15,0)`), and because of this everything breaks, even if I first manually cast the data to desired types, they are interpreted as strings.